# get checkbox checked on first click

Tags: android, checkbox

I am creating some checkboxes dynamically. I want to check only one checkbox at a time.I have achieved this using setChecked(false) method.Its working fine,the problem is that when I unchecked first checkbox and click on second one then its getting checked at second time.I want it to be checked at first time.

Code that I have used-

```
 cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
 {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked)
   {
      Log.e("isChecked",""+isChecked);
      if(isChecked==true)
      {
        count++;
        sendData(j);

        if(count>1)
        {
            //cb[i].setChecked(false);
            buttonView.setChecked(false);
            count=0;
        }
     }
  };
```

Comment: how you are adding it?are you providing id for each checkbox?

Comment: @yuva-I am adding it in for loop. I am not providing any id but if it is needed then I can provide it.

Comment: @NehaAgarwal : how about adding [Radio Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) in same [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@neha try this...

```
@Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        if(count==0)
                        {
                            count++;
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "count="+count, 0).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        buttonView.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count--;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "count="+count, 0).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ..

```
  if(isChecked==true)
```

after this I think it will work as per your requierment...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `count` variable according to `check` and `uncheck` *clicks* -

Try like this -

```
int i;
int count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    cb.setTag(Integer.valueOf(i));
    cb.setText("CheckBox " + i);
    cb.setChecked(false);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.e("isChecked",""+isChecked);

            if (isChecked) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count--;
            }

            if (count > 1) {
                buttonView.setChecked(false);
                count--;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Wont this uncheck the currently checked checkbox? I guess he want the current checkbox checked and make the previous one unchecked..

Comment: @AcidBurn - Initially `count = 0`, then he checked the checkbox. Now `count = 1`. Then he again check another checkbox. Now `count = 2`. So `buttonView.setChecked` will become false and he will see that checkbox as unchecked. This way, one checkbox will be seen as checked always.

Comment: okok i misunderstood the need. I thought he needed a radiobutton like selection.

Comment: @VedPrakash-Its not working. Even checkbox is not clicking with this code.